# How to find the highest three-digit "special" number on excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Im trying to use excel to find the highest 3 digit number, which the sum of the cubes of the digits that compose that number is equal to the number itself
Ex: 3^3 + 7^3 + 1^3 = 371

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The OP has not tagged e.g. "VBA", so the assumption that "scripts" are being sought is not justified. What's more, the question may not contain much information, but that information is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: @XORLX Before correcting others, please read the guidelines of what is a good question and what is not. This question is very low quality for SU. Take a look at **[ask]** to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

**Array formula****

`=99+MATCH(1,0/(MMULT(MID(ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999)),{1,2,3},1)^3,{1;1;1})=ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999))))`

As way of an explanation, the portion:

`ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999))`

generates an array of integers from 100 to 999 inclusive. It is a rigorous and minimally volatile (in fact, volatile at workbook open only, as I understand: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) construction which, for that reason, is preferable to both the fully volatile:

`ROW(INDIRECT("100:999"))`

and the non-volatile, though unrigorous (namely, susceptible to row insertions within the worksheet):

`ROW(100:999)`

(or `ROW($100:$999)` - the use of absolute referencing does not in any way affect the aforementioned susceptibility.)

Since we wish to consider each of the 3 digits within each of these 900 entries, we apply `MID` with an array of *start_num* parameters, such that:

`MID(ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999)),{1,2,3},1)`

which is:

`MID({100;101;102;103;104;105;...;999},{1,2,3},1)`

i.e.

`{"1","0","0";"1","0","1";"1","0","2";"1","0","3";"1","0","4";"1","0","5";,,,;"9","9","9"}`

We then take the cube of each of these values, such that:

`MID(ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999)),{1,2,3},1)^3`

which is:

`{"1","0","0";"1","0","1";"1","0","2";"1","0","3";"1","0","4";"1","0","5";,,,;"9","9","9"}^3`

gives:

`{1,0,0;1,0,1;1,0,8;1,0,27;1,0,64;1,0,125;,,,;729,729,729}`

`MMULT` is then used to sum each of the 900 triplets within this array, such that:

`MMULT(MID(ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999)),{1,2,3},1)^3,{1;1;1})`

which is:

`MMULT({1,0,0;1,0,1;1,0,8;1,0,27;1,0,64;1,0,125;,,,;729,729,729},{1;1;1})`

i.e.:

`{1;2;9;28;65;126;,,,;2187}`

All that remains is to determine the last (i.e. largest) occurrence for which the value in this resultant array is equal to the original value itself, such that the comparison:

`MMULT(MID(ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,105)),{1,2,3},1)^3,{1;1;1})=ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999))`

which is:

`{1;2;9;28;65;126;,,,;2187}={100;101;102;103;104;105;,,,;999}`

i.e.:

`{FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;,,,;FALSE}`

Reciprocation of this array with zero produces:

`{#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;,,,;#DIV/0!}`

i.e. an array whose entries are only either 1 (if the entry prior to reciprocation was `TRUE`) or `#DIV/0!` (if the entry prior to reciprocation was `FALSE`).

As such, when we now pass this array to `MATCH` with a *match_type* parameter of 1 (or, equivalently, omitted), it is of a suitable form such that we can return the relative position of the last numerical value which is less than our choice of *lookup_value* (1 here, though any numerical value greater than zero would also suffice).

Hence:

`MATCH(1,0/(MMULT(MID(ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999)),{1,2,3},1)^3,{1;1;1})=ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999))))`

which is:

`MATCH(1,{#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;,,,;#DIV/0!})`

returns 308.

Since the array we passed for consideration began at 100, not 1, we must of course add 99 on to this value, such that:

`99+MATCH(1,0/(MMULT(MID(ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999)),{1,2,3},1)^3,{1;1;1})=ROW(INDEX(A:A,100):INDEX(A:A,999))))`

which is

`99+308`

returns 407, which I therefore conclude is the answer to the OP's question.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: For the sake of improvement and being useful for others who may find this answer, rather than just provide a formula (because we are not a script/formula writing service), can you explain how this answers the question, how it works and details of how to implement it? Without details in the question, how do you know what cells the OP's data is in?

Comment: @CharlieRB I will add an explanation. FYI the formula does not explicitly reference the content of any worksheet cells. The choice of A:A is here arbitrary and independent of the actual content of those cells.